# Jquery Show/hide

Tags: jquery, function, hide, show

I'm trying to make simple jquery code for show/hide function.
But still I'm doing something wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.arrow').click(function() {
        $('#box').show("slow");     
    });

    $('.arrow').click(function() {
        $('#box').hide("slow");
    }); 
    $('.arrow').click(function() {
        $('#box').show("slow");     
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Armgh/

Answer (score 7):

use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.arrow').click(function() {
        $('#box').toggle('slow');       
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Armgh/1/

or you can save your status and toggle manually:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hidden = false;
    $('.arrow').click(function() {
        if (hidden) {
            hidden = true;
            $('#box').hide("slow");
        } else {
            hidden = false;
            $('#box').show("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Armgh/

**EDIT**

to use [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)/[`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hidden = false;
    $('.arrow').click(function() {
        if (hidden) {
            hidden = false;
            $('#box').slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            hidden = true;
            $('#box').slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Armgh/3/

or use [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.arrow').click(function() {
        $('#box').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Armgh/4/

Comment: Ok is work good, left question when i change toogle to slieDown and slideUp what happens? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use .toggle function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.arrow').click(function() {
        $('#box').toggle("slow");     
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use any toggle with [`slow`, `medium`, `fast`] parameter also,

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.arrow').on('click', function() {
            $('#box').toggle("slow");  
        });
    });
```